# Cannot assign to value: 'message' is a 'let' constant in a fucntion

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a function that checks if a value is nil and if it is give it a default value.  This is what I have so far:

```
func appendMessage(message: String?, fixLength: Int){
        if let message = message {
        } else {
             message = DEFAULT_CHAR//this is a default value, error is here
        }
          messageBody.append(getFixedLengthString(message, fixLength))
    }
```

Comment: Function input arguments are immutable in `Swift`, hence the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the error for the obvious reason that the `message` parameter is a constant. Inside the `else` you are attempting to update the `message` parameter. The `message` variable created via the `if let` is also a constant but its scope is only inside the `if`, not the `else` nor after the whole `if/else` block. So the `message` variable you are attempting to use in the call to `getFixedLengthString` is the original `message` parameter.

The simplest solution is to use the `??` (nil-coalescing) operator:

```
func appendMessage(message: String?, fixLength: Int){
    messageBody.append(getFixedLengthString(message ?? DEFAULT_CHAR, fixLength))
}
```

The `??` operator returns the value on the left if it isn't `nil` and the value on the right if the left side is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to understand more of your logic/code, then you would solve it pretty easily.

This one should work.

```
func appendMessage(message: String?, fixLength: Int) {
    if let message = message {
        messageBody.append(getFixedLengthString(message, fixLength))
    } else {
         messageBody.append(getFixedLengthString(DEFAULT_CHAR, fixLength))
    }
}
```

Perhaps you can also try this one liner:

```
messageBody.append(getFixedLengthString(message == nil ? DEFAULT_CHAR : message!, fixLength))
```